# How to use arara with a makeindex style file to add capital letters to index

Tags: indexing, makeindex, arara

I would like to augment my LaTeX **index** with a capital letter to distinguish each letter category. For example;

> **A**
>
> ample
> axe
>
> **B**
>
> block
> buy

and so on. I've created a **makeindex style** file, `MyLatex.ist`, containing the following code (see [https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8096](http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8096)):

```
headings_flag 1
heading_prefix "\\textbf\{\\huge "
heading_suffix "\}\}"
```

When I add the following line to my **arara** code:

```
% arara: makeindex { style: MyLatex.ist }
```

I get the following error upon compile:

> I spotted an invalid directive (15) in the provided file. Make sure to fix the directive and try again.

I've tried a number of different configurations (not shown here), with NO success.

My question is how can I use **arara** with a `MyLatex.ist` style file to have **makeindex** add the **capital** letters to my **index**? Or, is there another, more straightforward way to have the **capital** letters added to my **index** to obtain the results I'm looking for.

Comment: @Bernard - Thank you for the edits!

Comment: @epR8GaYuh - Thank you for cleaning up my question!

Comment: Try with `heading_suffix "\}"`. `\textbf{}` takes an argument, inside the braces, but `\huge` is just a switch and has no braces.

Comment: `% arara: makeindex: { style: MyLatex.ist }` (notice the colon after makeindex).

Comment: @TeXnician - Your comment was spot on, Thank you (now how do I respond to give you credit?)

Comment: @Cicada - I've been able to implement the capital letter in the index, but am unable to BOLD the single letter ... I've discovered there is a 2nd '.ist' file that somehow is dynamically created by the glossaries package, the first line of which reads: "% makeindex style file created by the glossaries package". I'm stumped as to what to do next. Apologies that I did NOT see this previously. I have NO idea if/how the two '.ist' files may be interacting, but I'm guessing it's the reason your suggestion is not working as it should.

Comment: @Cicada - The heading_prefix and heading_suffix in the 2nd '.ist' file reads: heading_prefix "\\glsgroupheading\{"
heading_suffix "\}\\relax \\glsresetentrylist ".
Is there a way I can combine both to add a BOLD capital character to my index?

Comment: A solution will depend on what is actually running. I cannot guess what packages, options and settings are in use, and have nothing to test potential solutions against, because no compilable example document has been given (minimum working example, MWE). Try and create an MWE. It will get to an answer faster than guessing. A glossary should come out separately to an index, right? Or do you want the glossary only, and no index? Or both in one? And so on.

Comment: The `glossaries` package documentation (do `texdoc glossaries`) mentions `indexgroup`. Do you have a line `\usepackage[style=indexgroup]{glossaries}` in the preamble? Plus, according to (https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/buildglossaries/), your MakeIndex tool should be set up with your editor's equivalent of `makeindex -s basename.ist -o basename.gls -t basename.glg basename.glo`, where **basename** will be replaced with the name of your `.tex` file. (My one needs $basename, for example.)

Comment: @Cicada - I will look at creating a MWE ... it might take a bit of time ... perhaps I'll discover what is going on in doing so. Thank you for all your help ... in the meantime, until we have an answer, is there anything I can do to give you credit? Thank you!